# rxjs pass forkjoin a function which return a array of observables

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a function which returns an array of Observables

```
function getMultipleObservables() {
    let coordinationObservables: Observable<any>[] = [];
    coordinationObservables.push(Observable.of([1,2,3,4]))
    coordinationObservables.push(Observable.of([1,2,3,4]))
    return coordinationObservables
}
```

I have another part of code chains multiple observables like this:

```
this.someService.flatMap(()=>{
    return Observable.forkJoin((getMultipleObservables())=>{
        //handle the responses
    })
}).subscribe(()=>{

})
```

So my question is how could I properly pass a function as a parameter to the forkJoin, and handle it in the callback function.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator.

```
return Observable.forkJoin(...getMultipleObservables()).map((data) => {
     // do something, write your code here
     // later subscribe it wherever it is returning
     // using map() like this is works for rxjs < 5.5,
     // use it under pipe() if you have a higher version
     // like: forkjoin(...getMultipleObservables()).pipe(map());
     return modifiedData // if modified, else no need to add map
})
```